# Why foreign key field in serializer of django rest-frame work become read only?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models as below

```
class Cluster(models.Model):

    _id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, null=False, default=uuid.uuid1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False)

class Node(models.Model):
    _id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, null=False, default=uuid.uuid1)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=False, unique=True)
    cluster = models.ForeignKey(Cluster, on_delete=models.PROTECT, to_field='_id')
```

As you can see above. The node will have a foreign key reference to cluster  which means the node belongs to one cluster. **I use a unique key filed _id to be the foreign key instead of  the primary  key.**

Then I create a serializer

```
class NodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Node
        fields = ('_id', 'ip', 'cluster_id')
```

The  serializer works fine when retrieve data from database. But has problem when  creating

```
>>> print(NodeSerializer())
NodeSerializer():
    _id = UUIDField(required=False, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Node.objects.all())>])
    ip = IPAddressField(validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Node.objects.all())>])
    cluster_id = ReadOnlyField()
```

Because the cluster_id is READ  ONLY, so serializer.validated_data will always miss the field cluster_id.

So how could I create node with  this serializer?

Answer (score 2):

`cluster_id` is extra attribute generated by ForeignKey. You should use `cluster` to make field writable:

```
class NodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Node
        fields = ('_id', 'ip', 'cluster')
```

Or use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` with source argument to rename field on serializer level:

```
class NodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cluster_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='cluster', queryset=Cluster.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = models.Node
        fields = ('_id', 'ip', 'cluster_id')
```

Comment: The Second way will raise Exception "AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`."

Comment: @KramerLi forgot about queryst. Check updated answer.

Comment: Now I have this error "{'cluster_id': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid pk "af9463d8-c3c7-11e8-82e7-f000ac192ced" - object does not exist.', code='does_not_exist')]}". The foreign key I  using is not pointing to a pk. It is pointing to a unique key column. Is that a problem?

Comment: @KramerLi yes you should provide primary key.

Comment: but the foreign key of node is not pointing  to  the pk of cluster model. it is pointing to a _id field  which is a uuid field. Also can you help to explain what the queryset is used for here? I read  that part  on official doc, but just do not understand what queryset  for here. Thanks

Comment: @KramerLi `queryset` option is using to specify which Cluster objects can be used as the value of `cluster_id` field. In your case it's all Clusters.

Comment: Does django  rest-frame work serializer only support primary key  based foreign key? Can I use foreign key that  point to a unique column?

Comment: @KramerLi you'd better make this field your model's primary key using `primary_key` argument: `_id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, null=False, default=uuid.uuid1, primary_key=True)`